# OS X: What does the '@' attribute on a file mean?

Tags: mac-osx, unix

On a Snow Leopard machine, at the Terminal:

```
la ~/src/rmcl/ | grep RMCL
-rw-r--r--@  1 claytonstanley  staff  6766167 Nov 13  2009 RMCL
```

What is that '@' attribute?

This file is part of an older OS X program that runs under Rosetta. I'm having issues where some older programs running under Rosetta require the @ attribute when opening files. But I'm not sure what that attribute is, so I have no way to know how to add/remove it.

I did try a thorough Google search on this, but I wasn't able to find the answer. I would have thought this would be an easy one to find. Maybe the Google query isn't acting properly because of the single @ special character.

Any info. is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Already asked and answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean

Comment: yeah it's a part of extended attribute. OSX uses this attribute extensively to point the user that the file was not originated from the current machine. You will see this attribute set for all your downloaded file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's for extended attributes.

Try `ls -la@e` to display them. You can use normal `chmod` to set them (check out `man chmod`).

Answer (score 4):

Basically what the other guy said.
It is for extended attributes.
You can use `xattr -l` as well to get some information.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a nice article about the extended attributes (the files with the @ sign) of OS X here

http://xahlee.blogspot.de/2010/07/os-x-extended-attributes-and-xattr.html